# Need a list on my parent site to appear on a child site Sharepoint 2007

Tags: site

I have 2 lists on my parent site that are public lists we used to gather and document training development requests and course revision requests. I have a child site that our development group utilizes for our meetings - this is not a public site - it is only for the team.  Currently when ever we get a development request or a revision request on the parent site, I take the information from the requests and populate 2 different separate lists on my child site. I would like to streamiine this process and have all entries on my parent site lists automatically populate lists on my child site.  These can be clones of the parent site lists - whatever works. I have sharepoint designer - but have never used it.

Comment: By Child Site do you mean your development team uses a subsite and business users only interact with the top level site ?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a SharePoint designer you can create a workflow between Master and Child list. The workflow will update/delete/add the items to the children lists accordingly, and both lists will be synced.

Here is a practical example: http://www.hexanes.com/?p=897

Comment: the workflow option doesnt seem to solve this problem. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: what problem do you see while using Workflows? I have updated my response with an example solution.

Comment: your answer is still wrong that workflow trick is for updating lists on the same site... he wants to update a list on a different site.